# How can I reenable admin privileges without an administrative user?

Tags: macos

I installed server and fiddling around settings and I unchecked administer this account and the server crashed immediately.

Now I am listed as standard user and cannot perform any changes:

```
$ dscl . -read /groups/admin GroupMembership
GroupMembership: root
```

I thought there will be atleast 1 user to administer the whole computer excluding root :(. How can I get back. Quite panicked as I might loose everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try whether `sudo -s` still works (which would allow you to add yourself to the admin group again), but probably it won't.

Do the following

- Reboot into Single User mode by keeping <kbd>Cmd-S</kbd> pressed during reboot
- `/sbin/mount -uw /`
- `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone`
- `reboot`

This will trick your Mac into behaving like a new installation (but with your data still intact). Follow the setup without migrating any data etc., near the end you will have the option to create a new user with admin privileges. Make sure to pick a new username here to avoid any conflicts.