# Administrator account apparently lost after forced reboot of OS X

Tags: macos, user-account, administrator

Yesterday I ran into one of those rare problems with OS X (10.11.4) where I thought I had to reboot my MacBook. The cursor wheel was constantly spinning and I was unable to quit any apps or even access `Force Quit ...`. (This was triggered inside Firefox.) So a reboot seemed like an easy way out.

Unfortunately the reboot seems to have corrupted the setup in a bad way. I normally have two user accounts on the MacBook, like `A` and `B`, where `A` is also the administrator account.

After the reboot `A` now seems to have disappeared. It e.g. does not show up under `System Preferences` | `Users`, nor in `/etc/passwd`. It is also no longer available as a choice in `Login Window ...`. The lost account's files still seem to remain under `/Users/A/`, but I can no longer access them because I no longer have administrator privileges.

I this a know problem (perhaps even an indication of malware)? How can I restore account `A` and its administrator privileges without risking corruption of its (presumably) remaining original files in `/Users/A/`? (At least I do have recent Time Machine backups and can log in as `B`.)

Comment: If you have a Time Machine backup, why not just restore?

Comment: @IronCraftMan This would seem to make the situation worse (i.e. overwrite all files on my MacBook) before it makes it better. I'd prefer to try something like the following first: 1) obtain administrator privileges for `B`; 2) rename `/Users/A` to `/tmp/X`; 3) recreate account `A`; 4) replace `/Users/A` by `/tmp/X`; 5) shift administrator rights from `B` back to `A`. That's at least the theory ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was lucky. Booting into Single User Mode (for obtaining administrator privileges as described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/58860/31610)) apparently caused some extra disk check. This presumably led to the restoration of some corrupted piece of (meta)data and in effect my account `A`, including its previous administrator privileges.

Looks as if the system is back to normal now: much relief!